# Is there any limit to editing of self asked questions?

Tags: discussion

I had asked a question long back which was resolved, but at the same moment due to increase of downvotes on some of my other questions, I wasn't able to ask more questions.

So, I tried to edit one of my downvoted questions to ask a completely new one, but as the new question asked was completely different from the previous edited one the question was closed and locked.

If the edit had disabled changing/adding new tags then I wouldn't have faced this issue. So, for future purposes: Are there any edit restrictions in terms of limit, privileges, etc. for self-asked questions?

Comment: You were, but aren't currently question banned. Do note that your next question better be a great one.

Comment: It is generally accepted as a general rule that you shouldn't edit a question to ask a completely different one, as it may contradict any previous answers or backlinks it might have got. Plus it makes for a messy and inconsistent edit history.

Comment: You may want to read on [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @SamuelLiew "...next question be a better one" I dont make questions out here. It was the problem I had faced and if you could tell me what was wrong in the above question itll be really helpful to me

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That really helped. Thanks.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi Agreed, I shouldnt have replaced with a completely new one but the fact that i was unaware at that time perhaps the edit shouldve disabled changing/adding of tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, for future purposes just wanted to know are there any edit restrictions in terms of limit, privillages etc for self asked questions

There are only a few restrictions regarding editing and it seems that you fell into the trap of one of them:

> So, I tried to edit one of my downvoted questions **to ask a completely new one but as the new question asked was completely different from the previous edited one the question was closed and locked**.

(emphasis mine)

The question was rightfully closed and locked because when you change your original question it automatically invalidates any of the existing answers that contributors spent time to research and answer, as a result, when people come across your (now changed) question it'll seem as though the previous answers are answering something completely different and they'll receive negative feedback due to no fault of their own.

The general rule of thumb is not to amend your original code or question.

If however, you do wish to adjust the code, append the new version of the code as a update, don't replace previous versions.

If you have another follow-up question that is unrelated to your current question, feel free to ask another question.

As far as general editing etiquette goes, it is best to try and make your edits as thorough as possible to prevent filling the edit history with lots of entries.

Comment: Additionally, disabling tag editing wouldn't have prevented OP from doing what they did if their "new" question was roughly classifiable under the same tags as their "old" one.

Comment: @Script47 At that moment, I was unaware as I was not able to ask new questions be the only sole reason I had edited that perhaps if there was adding/changing of tags disabled i wouldnt have faced this much.